# Sort by full number in axis

Tags: powerbi

Is it possible somehow to sort the columns by ending full number?

[image]

As you can see Month 10 i number 2. Or is there other approaches to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the data type of the column is text, 1,10,100 ending would be considered 1st as compared to 2,3 etc.
So you need to sort that column by some other column as seen below:
[image]

You can create a mapping table mapping Month1>1 ; MOnth2>2 etc and Leverage it.

Hope this is what you are asking for :)