# How to Sort years in ascending or descending orders in power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have my data like -

| Course_Code | Source |
| --- | --- |
| Learning | 2019-20 |
| BAC | 2019-20 |
| SC_casting | 2019-20 |
| Rubber melt | 2019-20 |
| Learning | 2018-19 |
| Casting | 2018-19 |
| BAC | 2018-19 |
| Learning | 2020-21 |
| Learning | 2020-21 |
| Learning | 2020-21 |

When I have created a chart I have taken **values** - "count of course code" (count distinct)

and in **Axis** - "Source"

my chart looks like

**2020-21** -------------- **59**

**2018-19** ----------------------- **79**

**2019-20** ---------------------------- **104**

the dashes are my bars of horizontal bar charts and the years are my Y axis

what I want is to sort the source like -

**2020-21** -------------- **59**

**2019-20** ---------------------------- **104**

**2018-19** ----------------------- **79**

Is there any way to do that in power BI?
I am new to power bi

Comment: You just have to change the sort property of the visual to use Source instead of the measure, that is the default when creating the chart visual.

Answer (score 0):

since the data type of that column is text , it would sort the data as per text in either asc or desc format.
So in order for you to have the axis as per month order, create a new column of type integer (202012 etc) and sort the text column with this column.

Similar Refr:
[Sort by full number in axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65468579/sort-by-full-number-in-axis/65472893#65472893)